# Test if a workbook contains password protected chart sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to test whether worksheets are password protected in the specified workbook `objXL`.

```
Function IsProtected(objXL As Object) As Boolean
Dim wksht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Select Case TypeName(objXL)
Case "Worksheet"
If objXL.ProtectContents Then
IsProtected = True
Exit Function
End If
Case "Workbook"
If objXL.ProtectStructure Then
IsProtected = True
Exit Function
End If
For Each wksht In objXL.Worksheets
If wksht.ProtectContents Then
IsProtected = True
Exit Function
End If
Next wksht
Case "Range"
If objXL.Cells.Count = 1 Then
If (objXL.Locked And objXL.Parent.ProtectContents) Or (IsProtected(objXL.Parent.Parent)) Then
IsProtected = True
Exit Function
End If
Else
For Each cell In objXL
If (cell.Locked And cell.Parent.ProtectContents) Or (IsProtected(cell.Parent.Parent)) Then
IsProtected = True
Exit Function
End If
Next cell
End If

End Select
End Function
```

The function fails to detect chart sheets that are password protected. Any ideas how I can modify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should work if you loop through all the sheets instead of all the worksheets (which don't include chart sheets).  Try running the codes below in a workbook with chart sheets and see the difference.

```
Sub wkshts()

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Name = Name & " " & ws.Name & vbNewLine    
Next
MsgBox Name
End Sub

Sub shts()

For Each ws In sheets
    Name = Name & " " & ws.Name & vbNewLine
Next
MsgBox Name
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work. I wouldn't mind having a separate function just to test Chart sheets as this is getting complicated now.